# Why my stacknavigator works with one screen and not with another one?

Tags: react-native, navigation, navigator, stack-navigator

I want to navigate accross screens from a Camera screen to a summary screen but it doesn't work:

```
        // Camera screen
        if (data.data){
            const data = {date,name,place}

           Alert.alert(
               'Info', 'Show', 
                [{text: 'More', onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Summary')}],          
               )
        })}
```

I already defined a stack navigator like below:

```
        //Navigator file
        import SummaryScreen from  '../screens/SummaryScreen';

         export const SummaryStack = createStackNavigator({
         Summary : SummaryScreen
         });
```

Funny thing is that when I replace `this.props.navigation.navigate('Summary')` by `this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')` , it works.

Here is the homescreen navigator:

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
Home: HomeScreen
});

const ScanStack = createStackNavigator({
Camera: CameraScreen
});

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
HomeStack,
CameraStack
});
```

Comment: Can we see the root navigation, cause from what I see it's normal Summary dont work cause you need to add this one to the root navigation who here I think is your createBottomTabNavigator.

Comment: I didn't define any root navigation, only stcacknavigators. I created a bottom tab in my home page, hence createBottomTabNavigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work add the SummaryStack to your home stack

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
   Home: HomeScreen,
   Summary: SummaryStack
});
```

Comment: Nice happy to hear that :) Can you make it as the answer :)